# marker.showInfoWindow() has no effect using google map API V2 Lite Mode

Tags: android, google-maps

Google doc is very clear about using showInfoWindow with Markers in Lite Mode:

> if you set the title() of a marker, the default info window will
>   appear when the user taps the marker. ***You can show the info window
>   programmatically by calling showInfoWindow() on the marker.*** You can
>   also create custom info windows via the InfoWindowAdapter interface.
>   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/lite

Here is a part of my code:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {

        }
    });
    googleMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng) {

        }
     });

    googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            marker.showInfoWindow();
            return true;
        }
    });

    BitmapDescriptor skierIcon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.skiericon);
    markers.add(googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(mountain_latitude+0.01, mountain_longitude+0.01))
            .title("Bob")
            .visible(true)
            .icon(skierIcon)));


    markers.add(googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(mountain_latitude-0.01, mountain_longitude-0.01))
            .title("Alice")
            .icon(skierIcon)));
    for(Marker marker: this.markers){
        marker.showInfoWindow();
        boolean ret = marker.isInfoWindowShown();
    }
}
```

**My problem is that marker.isInfoWindowShown() always returns false.**

Here is how I call it

```
        fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.map, mapFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

Comment: but your markers are being shown?

Comment: Yes , the markers work correctly

Answer (score 0):

Remember the rendering of the map is an asynchronous process, you create your Markers inside `onMapReady()` and after the execution of this method, then you can check if your markers are being shown.

Comment: Isn't getMapAsync() a non-blocking async function? If yes, checking markers should be done once we make sure that the map is rendered, in onMapReady() callback.

Comment: you must check isInfoWindowShown() after the execution of onMapReady().